# How to set Google Drive to authorize Auth0 domain?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, auth0, google-developers-console

I wish to use Google Drive API to get a file content from Google Drive through Auth0: https://auth0.com/.

[image: here]

And when I try to link the google drive account with Auth0, it displays the following:

[image: here]

How to set Google Drive to authorize Auth0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Requesting verification**

You can request a verification of the OAuth client used by your app and its Cloud project. Once your app is verified, your users will no longer see the unverified app screen. In addition, your app will no longer be subject to the user cap.

**Requirements**

In order to submit your OAuth client for verification, you must own a web site on a domain. The site must host publicly-accessible pages that describe your app and its privacy policy. You must also verify your ownership of the site with Google.

You do not need to publish your app from an account in this domain, but the domain owner must be an editor or owner of the script project.

In addition, you must have the following required assets:

- Application name. The name of the app; this is displayed on the consent screen. It should match the name used for the app in other locations, such as the G Suite Marketplace listing for published apps.
- Application logo. A app logo JPEG, PNG, or BMP image to use in the consent screen. Its file size must be 1MB or less.
- Support email. This is an email displayed on the consent screen for users to contact if they need app support. It can be your email address or a Google Group that you own or manage.
- Scopes. The list of all the scopes your app uses. You can view your scopes in the Apps Script editor.
- Authorized domains. This is a whitelist of domains containing information about your app. All your application's links (such as its required privacy policy page) must be hosted on authorized domains.
- Application homepage URL. The location of a homepage describing your app. This location must hosted on an authorized domain.
- Application privacy policy URL. The location of a page describing your app's privacy policy. This location must be hosted on an authorized domain.
  In addition to the above required assets, you can optionally provide an Application terms of service URL that points to a page describing your app's terms of service. If provided, this location must be in an authorized domain.

You can read more about it here [requesting verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#requesting_verification) remember this is done though google not auth0

I have submitted a documentation issue with auth0 [6946](https://github.com/auth0/docs/issues/6946)  I suspect that this is not going to work as you cant verify the domain.  However i will let them deal with their documentation.